# Disable days from array with react-day-picker in react

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

I'm using react-day-picker and I try to disable an array of dates from an axios function like this :

```
this.state = {
  dateDisabled: [],
}

componentDidMount() {
axios.get(URL_GET_DATE)
  .then(response => {
    const date = response.data;
    this.setState({
      dateDisabled: date
    })
  })
```

}

Also my state dateDisabled become like this when I console.log:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
`0: date_arrivee: "2020-04-07T21:00:00.000Z" date_depart: "2020-04-10T21:00:00.000Z"
`1: date_arrivee: "2020-03-24T22:00:00.000Z"date_depart: "2020-03-30T21:00:00.000Z"
```

I would like to have the same result as here ->

```
disabledDays={[
    {
      after: new Date(2017, 3, 20),
      before: new Date(2017, 3, 25),
    },
  ]}
/>
```

[Display days as disabled](https://react-day-picker.js.org/examples/disabled)

How my dates could become before and after props ?
Thank you and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array to achieve this result:

```js
const dates = [{
  date_arrivee: "2020-04-07T21:00:00.000Z",
  date_depart: "2020-04-10T21:00:00.000Z"
}, {
  date_arrivee: "2020-03-24T22:00:00.000Z",
  date_depart: "2020-03-30T21:00:00.000Z",
}];

const transformedDates = dates.map((date)=>{
  return {
    before: new Date(date.date_arrivee),
    after: new Date(date.date_depart),
  }
});

console.log(transformedDates);
```

You can set the `transformedDates` to state and then feed this to React Day Picker.

Comment: Oh my god, yes thank you, sometimes we forget the basics haha